# Wifi Access Point frequently drops ping packets to 192.168.1.1

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, wireless-access-point

In our 5-story office, there is one main router connected to the modem and each other level has one Wifi Access Point each connected by LAN to the main router. The trouble is that these Wifi APs frequently lose connection to the main router, that is when pinging to 192.168.1.1 they drop most, if not all, of the packets. However, during this same time LAN connection to the AP usually works fine. So it's just the wifi that loses connection. Everything is setup correctly, that is all of the AP has DHCP off and they all use different channels (either 1, 6 or 11 usually). The APs are of various make and models, including some TP-Links and Buffalos. I appreciate any ideas you can give. Thank you!

Comment: Hmm, tp-link and Buffalo don't sound like routers/ap's that should be in this role honestly. What's a guesstimate of the total number of client devices connected to each access point? If you are stuck with these devices, you may want to look into getting third party firmware on them. (Dd-wrt/openWRT) at least then you can get some snmp action going to try and figure out what's physically going on with memory, CPU, bandwidth, interfaces etc.

Comment: It sounds like you're only using 2.4GHz and your wifi network has no controller and is just a bunch of individual access points. You could be suffering from interference in 2.4GHz, incorrect channel plans, different AP interfering/competing with each other. I would recommend moving to 5GHz and using a single vendor solution. An onsite survey or predictive survey could be the solution.

Comment: @Tim_Stewart thanks for your reply. Why do you say TP-link and Buffalo are not suitable? number of client devices anywhere between 50 to 100 at any given point. How do you check "snmp"? What does that tell you? Thank you.

Comment: @CustomX thanks for your comment. That is right mostly using 2.4 GHz and no controller and a bunch of APs. Some of the APs have 5GHz, but not all of the clients, particularly laptops, can see that frequency and I'm not sure why. I guess their Wifi modules don't support 5GHz. Does single-vendor really make much difference? I thought all of these APs were more or less the same....

Comment: @rabbid, 50-100 total? Or per floor? "I thought all of these APs were more or less the same?" ~ no, they can be vastly different from the same manufacturer and different version numbers of the same model.

Comment: @rabbid, I hope it's 50-100 clients throughout the building and not per AP. TP-Link isn't really used in office environments here in Europe (I don't even know Buffalo). Single vendor is better because your wireless is interconnected and sessions can be passed on to one another, which should also improve roaming. Your AP will also (if enabled) adjust their TX power to each other. Just a rule of thumb; in 2.4GHz, use either channels 1-6-11 or 1-5-9-13 and limit your SSID to about 3.